# Filter table based on select value

Tags: jquery, html

I have read multiple topics and couldn't find the one that suits my needs.

This is an example:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Web Developer</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Web Designer</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Nicole</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Graphic Designer</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And this would be select option

```
<select>
<option value="developer">Developers</option>
<option value="designer">Designers/option>
</select>
```

So what I would need is that when "Designers" it will list only designers (graphic, web...).

How can I achieve this? Basically I'll have one option value but it will need to filter multiple table rows containing different content.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an attribute on your `tr` *(here `data-job`)* to keep track of each person's job and compare it to your option value on change of your select :

```js
$('#jobSelect').on('change',function(){
  $('#people tr').hide();
  $('#people tr[data-job="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="people">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-job="developer">
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Web Developer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-job="designer">
      <td>Michael</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Web Designer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-job="designer">
      <td>Nicole</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Graphic Designer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<select id="jobSelect">
  <option value="developer">Developers</option>
  <option value="designer">Designers</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't know which <tr> will have designer or developer since my values are Web Designer or Web Developer, and sometimes WP Developer which should be assigned as developer.

Comment: And also there could be other type of developers. Can I somehow have multiple values in option?

Comment: @David You're the one who's choosing the `data-job` of each `tr`, so if someone is Web Developer,  WP Developer, etc ... set `data-job` to `developer`.